# How to know if current plugin is going to be used while rendering the page?

Tags: plugin-development

In WordPress, how to know if current plugin is going to be used while rendering the page ? As far as I know, all plugins classes gets instantiated when page gets requested. 
Also, is there any way to get routing information in WordPress ?

Comment: Used for what? All plugins are loaded on every request. Whether they are likely to do anything on that page depends on what you're looking for. There's no catch all way to tell if a plugin is going to be 'used'.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am trying to load CSS/JS when plugin is going to be 'used'. How to prevent it loading when not in use ?

Comment: What does your plugin do? Does it provide shortcodes, blocks, something else? What kind of routing information do you need?